# Getpivot data Excel 2016 Date not recognised

Tags: date, excel-2016

Hi I've got a Pivot table for various products in a company i work for.  We have been moved to 2016 Excel and my New Pivot table is displaying the date after I formatted it in Access.

But, My `Getpivot` data does not recognise the date anymore.  Any suggestions?

3 excel files also running in Excel 2016 are okay because they have not been changed but this new workbook now has stopped working.

Example here:

```
=IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("QUANTITY",'Qry from PST db'!$A$2,"Day/Night",$T$14,"SUPPLIER",S15,"ShiftDatet","17/11/2015"),"N/A")
```

The date of 17/11/2015 should point to a cell in the workbook but then the query now fails but is okay in other workbooks.

Same formula in different book that works:

```
=IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("QUANTITY",'Qry from PST db'!$A$2,"Day/Night",$T$14,"SUPPLIER",S15,"ShiftDatet",$E$13),"n/a")
```

Comment: "does not recognize the date anymore" <-- seems like the data it is not formatted as 'date' in excel before/after the formatting change.